# Missing rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a data frame that is a subset of the original based on specific results in a column but it keeps excluding some of the data, specifically codes 59960, 59961, 59962.

I have also confirmed that the column includes the identifier I am parsing for using .unique()

Here is my code:

```
new_df = original_df[(original_df["Course Offering Code"] == 19191)|\
(original_df["Course Offering Code"] == 2201.20215)|\
(original_df["Course Offering Code"] == 2387.2205)|\
(original_df["Course Offering Code"] == 2388.20225)|\
(original_df["Course Offering Code"] == 59960.20211)|\
(original_df["Course Offering Code"] == 59961.20211)|\
(original_df["Course Offering Code"] == 59962.20211)|\
(original_df["Course Offering Code"] == 61199.20211)|\
(original_df["Course Offering Code"] == 61201.20211)|\
(original_df["Course Offering Code"] == 61202.20211)]
```

thank you!

Comment: What does `original_df["Course Offering Code"].dtype` return?

Comment: @BeRT2me it returns dtype('float64')
Note: I did shorten the values here for simplicity, so to be more clear i'll update my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is due to `float` comparisons that are not precise in pandas**.

You will have to either round it or use close comparisons. Having said that, it looks like Course offering codes are just *codes* and might *not* need to be `float64` - because technically a code can be represented by any unique number. Therefore, you can instead change the `Course Offering Code` column to `str` and select them instead, where you wont land into these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this instead...

```
codes = [19191, 2201, 2387, 59960, 59961, 59962, 61199, 61201, 61202]
new_df = original_df[original_df['Course Offering Code'].isin(codes)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the simpler code but remains the same issue. Updated post with full course offering code values in the event these are in someway causing the issue.

Comment: Ah, it's a floating point issue. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)